# How to get proper values from GridView when containing special characters (decode &#x;)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am current working on an asp.net page which allows user to update the details of a record. The language used is VB.Net. I am currently facing a problem whenever there is a special character in a string. The original data is bind to a Gridview from mySQL database.

For example, the name `Inocêncio`. Upon clicking the update button, it will be passed as a session to the Update page. The value is then set to a textbox. 
However, it appeared as `Inoc&#234;ncio`. This is just one of many examples which users will encounter.

Below will be my sample code:
From my Gridview to pass into a session

```
Session("ProviderDetails") = _
CStr(providerEscalationMatrixGridViewAdmin.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text)
```

I retrieved it this way

```
Dim contactName as String
contactName = Session("ProvidersDetails")
txtContact.text = contactName
```

I have tried 2 ways, first is to convert the variable which the session value has been assigned to.

```
 contactName = Regex.Unescape(contactName)
```

Second was `txtContact.Text = Regex.Unescape(txtContact.Text)`, but it still does not display as `Inocêncio`. Any help?

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "Upon clicking the update button, it will be passed as a session to the Update page. The value is then set to a textbox."? show some code, how to store in session and how you set textbox value

Comment: hi @S.Serp, i have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property of GridView Cell returns an encoded string, you have to decode it as following:

```
Session("ProviderDetails") = Server.HtmlDecode((providerEscalationMatrixGridViewAdmin.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text)
```

If you are outside an asp.net web app, you can use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` method .

Security Note: be aware of security issues it may have when you get string values from client side as it may be tampered by users...